# Error in running XSLT reports using ANT

Tags: java, eclipse, xslt, ant, selenium-ide

I have my Eclipse selenium project with few classes in it,I want to view the test reports in XSLT, my project has been complied and ran successfully through ANT, however when I try to run makexsltreports (either through Eclipse or through ANT command prompt am getting the below error:

> C:\Automation\Automation\build.xml:89: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found

Below is my build.xml:

```
<path id="test.c">
                            <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
                    </path>

                      <target name="makexsltreports">
                             <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

                 <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
                                 out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html"                classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">
                                <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>
                 <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>
                            </xslt>
                        </target>
```

Comment: I have added Saxon and SaxonLiason jars in project and class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because of missing JARs, Please add all required JAR files into project and class path and try again

Comment: @ Vinod : Thanks for pointing it out, it is because of missing XML JARS .. Issue got fixed now